# Is there a replacement for Paste.Template?

Tags: python, templates, generator

I have grown tired of all the little issues with paste template, it's horrible to maintain the templates, it has no way of updating an old project and it's very hard to test.

I'm wondering if someone knows of an alternative for quickstart generators as they have proven to be useful.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're correct. I did assume paste.template to be a template engine. If it helps any, I don't think there's a replacement for paste.template; Paste is a fairly specialized library with few (if any?) competitors or alternatives.

Comment: Checkout this alpha-level project: https://github.com/trentm/boilerplate

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used paste templates, so I'm not sure how it compares, but [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) seems like a fairly good system.

A snippet of the template language from their front page:

```
<%inherit file="base.html"/>
<%
    rows = [[v for v in range(0,10)] for row in range(0,10)]
%>
<table>
    % for row in rows:
        ${makerow(row)}
    % endfor
</table>

<%def name="makerow(row)">
    <tr>
    % for name in row:
        <td>${name}</td>\
    % endfor
    </tr>
</%def>
```

Comment: See the above comment. My problem is with the tool that uses the templates rather than the template code itself.